# Fragment/View. How to use a method on a View

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, nullpointerexception, navigation-drawer

I'm doing a Navigation Drawer app. I have all the cases working, I mean, when in touch a section the app goes to the right View. But when I want to start coding I don't know how to use methods inside the View. I think my code will explain better than me:

```
   public class News extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setText();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_news, container, false);
    }

    public void setText(){
        TextView texts = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
        texto.setText("hi");

    }
}
```

`NullPointerException` when I call the method setText. I know that it's the TextView definition, but I don't know how to "find" it in the layout without `getView()` or `getActivty()`, both return a `NullPointerException` when the view loads.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_news, container, false);
    setText(v);
    return v;
}
```

and

```
 public void setText(View v){
    TextView texts = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    texto.setText("hi");

}
```

Comment: TextView texts = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

"Cannot resolve symbol v"

Thanks for the reponse